# badRequest API response when running dataflow WordCount example

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to get google cloud dataflow to run. I am using a MacBook with MacOS 10.9.

I installed the google cloud sdk as well as the dataflow java sdk, following the instuctions of the [GitHubPage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK)

In order to get the dataflow sdk to compile with maven successfully, I had to set JAVA_HOME to the JDK 1.7 location.

In order to run the WordCount example, I had to install JDK 8 and use it as my runtime environment because otherwise I got the error that the "major.minor version is unknown: 51.0".

Now when I run the WordCount example with mvn (as suggested on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK)) the programs says it uploads 41 files to staging. After that, I get an API error:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

This is the command I run in the terminal:

```
mvn -e exec:java -pl examples   -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount   -Dexec.args="--project=${PROJECT} --stagingLocation=${STAGING} --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner --output=${OUTPUT}"
```

OUTPUT=gs://path/to/outfile.txt

STAGING=gs://path/to/staging (folder)

PROJECT=(numeric ID of project)

I believe that the PROJECT id is correct as well as the STAGING folder, as files are uploaded, according to the command line output.

The OUTPUT file does not exist yet, but the folder does.

I fail to see where the problem is, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

project should be the alphanumeric project id not the project number.

Sorry for the horrible error message. A more informative error message should be returned with the [1.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/java) or newer release of the SDK.

Comment: Yeah, it would be great to get some additional information on the "invalid argument".

Your answer was the solution.

I was under the assumption that if the upload of the files to staging works, the project id must be correct.

But it looks like the ProjectId is only needed for the execution of the Pipeline but not for preparing the data for processing.

Comment: The error message should be fixed in the [1.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/java) release of the SDK.